# Group results of grouped query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'd like to know how often a particular user does an activity on the same day

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Activity
GROUP BY entity_uid, date
```

This returns a long lists of counts: i.e.

```
1
1
2
1
```

I'd then like to group the results of this query that tell me how often each number appears within the result set, like this

```
#    Count(*)
1    3
2    1
```

Here's what I have, but it doesn't work

```sql
Select x = (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Activity
            GROUP BY entity_uid, date
           ),
       Count(*)
GROUP BY x
```

How can I select the results of a subquery in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
select daily_user_count, count(*) from (
SELECT COUNT(*) as daily_user_count FROM Activity
GROUP BY entity_uid, date
) Z
group by daily_user_count
```

Comment: What is the `Z` doing after the query.  It works with it, and doesn't work without it.

Comment: @KyleMit, `Z` is an alias for the [derived table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/vivekssqlnotes/2012/04/15/derived-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT Frequency, COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) Frequency 
    FROM Activity
    GROUP BY entity_uid, date
) t
GROUP BY Frequency
```